# I wanna make my hair straight permanently?

Tags: hair

I'm a male and I have a 5 inches curly long hair. I want to know if there's a way to make it permanently straight?

I want something without ironing

Answer (score 2):

A permanent relaxer will chemically straighten your hair. It can be achieved with at-home kits as well as a salon visit. The one caveat is that as you hair grows, the new hair will be untreated. This means that to keep your hair "relaxed" or straight you will need to retreat it about every eight weeks.